# How to use multiple models in a vbhtml view in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I guess this is a very simple question but I can't figure out the answer. I want to use multiple different models in a view in Asp.Net in Visual Basic (vbhtml). In C# (cshtml) I know I could do this like so:

```
 @using Namespace.Models;
```

As a reference at the top of the page. This doesn't work in VB. Does anyone know what the equivalent in VB is?

Comment: Actually you are asking two questions: 1) the equivalent of @using in vb and 2) how to use multiple models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called [Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type) statements in VB.NET.

```
Imports Namespace.Models
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a ViewModel i guess

```
public class model1{}

public class model2{}


public class ViewModel{
public model1 model {get;set;}
public model2 odel2 {get;set;}
}
```

just use the viewmodel as your model

P.S sorryt i am a C# dev so dont know about vb syntax